# How can I write characters to a file in Java?

Tags: java, file-handling

I want to write some characters to a file. For the purpose I wrote the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class write_char {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String name = "shahjahan.txt";

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(name));
        String text = " Hello, how are you?";

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < text.length() ; i++ )
        {
            outFile.write(text.charAt(i));
            outFile.write("\n");
            }
    }
}
```

But the file shahjahan.text is empty. I am novice to java. Please help me.

Is it necessary to close the file using close or flush. In C we donot require to close it.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your code, you need to call `.flush()` on the filewriter to do the writing. It's also a good practice to call `.close()` to tell the system you're done writing the file:

Add this after your for loop:

```
outFile.flush();
outfile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `close()`(or `flush()`) `outFile`

Eg:

```
String name = "yourText.txt";
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(name));
String text = " Hello, how are you?";
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    outFile.write(text.charAt(i));
    outFile.write("\n");
}
outFile.close(); // you missed this part
```